# $s_{k+1}=\left\lfloor\frac{s_kn}{k}\right\rfloor-s_k={n-1\choose k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, combinations

$$\hbox{Why }s_{k+1}=\left\lfloor\frac{s_kn}{k}\right\rfloor-s_k,\,s_0=0,\,s_1=1$$ $$\hbox{forms }{n-1\choose k-1}\hbox{?}$$
I saw it in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196306/41420) but have no explanation for this, alone to say I see it the first time while practicing math more than 15 years. Is it at least somehow known?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about this? With $n=6$ I'm getting [$s_4=1\neq\binom{5}{3}$](https://i.imgur.com/HLHc4hf.png).

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong with the indexes? For $6$ you get $s_1=1,s_2=6/1-1=5,s_3=5*6/2-5=10,s_4=10*6/4-10=5,s_5=5*6/5-6=1$

Comment: You are dividing by $k-1$, not $k$. Are you sure you need the $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is an *explanation*, but $$\left\lfloor\frac{s_kn}k\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{(n-1)!n}{(k-1)!(n-k)k}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\binom{n}{k}\right\rfloor=\binom n k,$$
so your recursion $s_k+s_{k+1}=\lfloor\frac{s_kn}k\rfloor$ is the familiar Pascal triangle recursion for generating the binomial coefficients.

(Composed while Luke Collins was posting his answer.)

Comment: The floor function is superfluous really, right?

Comment: @LukeCollins Seems so. Sad: it removes the charm from the question.

Comment: True, that's what made me click on it in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

Let me write it more simply, you want to show that if
$$s(n,k+1) = \begin{cases}
   \hfil1\hfil & \text{if $k=0$}\\[5pt]
   \frac{n}{k}s_k-s_{k} & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}$$
then $s(n,k)=\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

This is is simply the usual binomial identity $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}$ rewritten as $$\underbrace{\binom{n-1}{k}}_{s(n,k+1)}=\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\frac{n}{k}\underbrace{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}_{s(n,k)}-\underbrace{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}_{s(n,k)}.$$

---

Alternatively, you can prove it directly by induction on $k$. Indeed, when $k=1$, you have $s(n,k)=1=\binom{n-1}{0}$ for all $n$.
Now for the inductive case, we have

\begin{align*}
   s(n,k+1) = \frac{s_kn}{k}-s_k &= \frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1} - \binom{n-1}{k-1}\qquad\text{(induction hypothesis)}\\[5pt]
&= \binom{n-1}{k-1}\left(\frac{n-k}{k}\right)\\[5pt]
&= \frac{(n-1)!\,(n-k)}{(n-k)!\,(k-1)!\,k}\\[5pt]
&=\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-k)!\,k!}\\[5pt]
&= \binom{n-1}{k},
\end{align*}
as required.